# How to check if deletion was successful in the database?

Tags: java, mysql

I wanted an error to popup, when the user entered a wrong id into the delete field. But even if a wrong id is entered, the query still proceeds, but no data is deleted. Here's my code:

```
String value = jTextField19.getText();

if (value == null || "".equals(value)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The field is blank!");
} else {
    theQuery("DELETE FROM inventorydb WHERE item_id=('"+jTextField19.getText()+"') AND item_id IS NOT NULL");
}
```

The `theQuery` method:

```
private void theQuery(String query) {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory", "root", "");
        st = con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Done!");
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error!");
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is the runtime value of `value`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First of all: do not *ever* directly build SQL queries from user input, use prepared statements instead. If you don't know about SQL Injection, you should.

If you are using JDBC, you can check the result of `#executeUpdate()` to see how many rows were affected. If it was zero, then you can say that it was a wrong `id`.

This is the method definition:

```
public int executeUpdate(java.lang.String sql)
```

The return value is:

> An `int` that indicates the number of rows affected, or `0` if using a DDL statement.

---

In the program at hand, you can just simply do this:

```
int deleted = st.executeUpdate(query);
if (deleted == 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nothing to delete!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: can you explain briefly, im sorry im new in java programming language but im very eager to learn this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, and obligatory XKCD reference: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: btw this is theQuery statement that i called whenever user click the button:    private void theQuery(String query) {
         Connection con = null; 
        Statement st = null;
        try{ 
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory","root",""); 
            st = con.createStatement(); 
            st.executeUpdate(query); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Done!"); 
        }catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error!");
        }

    }

Comment: Next time, please add this to the question. Right now, I did it for you.

Comment: sorry man, thanks for editing the question back. do you mean i should add the code into theQuery method?

Comment: I meant that all relevant code should be included in the question, so it easier to answer it. It helps you, the answerers, and future readers.

Comment: Bro i tried using prepared statement but, it's not deleting item. try {
            Connection conn;
            conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnec­tion("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory","root","");
            final String queryCheck = ("delete from inventorydb WHERE item_id = ?");
    final PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
    ps.setString(1, jTextField19.getText());
    final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();      
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item not in database!");
        }

Comment: The delete script should not be used with `executeQuery`, as it has no `ResultSet` to return. Use `executeUpdate`.